# What is the best way to represent any TypeScript object in C# its Object or Dynamic

Tags: c#, typescript

```
var myAny : any;
var myDynamic : Dynamic : C#;
var myObj: Object;
```

what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Neither. What's the actual problem? Why are you using `any` in TypeScript? Why not eg generics?

Comment: function get any {} of properties  don't know really the the type of this properties

Comment: JavaScript has no types and yet objects have specific properties. When talking to the server, the DTOs are known. Which, by the way, is probably the only place where you'd want to convert a JavaScript object to a C# object. Unless the actual question is about Blazor-JavaScript interoperability?

Comment: typeScript has generics, so there's less need for `any`, for any function. Besides, you *do* know what the properties are - they are the properties used by that function. You could create an *interface* with those properties and methods, and stop passing `any`. You wouldn't even have to modify your input objects

Comment: Again, what's the *specific problem*? Why do you think converting to a catch-all type in C# would be a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you can avoid dynamic you should do so as it is better in most situations.

There are some converters online that can deal with converting typescript to c# objects.  e.g. quicktype:

https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

This uses the .NET Newtonsoft.Json library. Just paste in the typescript class on the left, and then add the c# code on the right to your project.

i've also had succes with this tool:

https://github.com/jburzynski/TypeGen